# How to create new directory in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to create UDF using java and to run on hive. In that UDF I need to specify the path for my Hadoop and need to create new directory in Hadoop.

My question is, How to create directory in hadoop using java ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html

FileSystem has a mkdir method.

Answer (score 1):

Hi dude you can create dir in hadoop.

hadoop fs -mkdir /user/dirname

Comment: This does not answer the question... _How to create directory in hadoop_ **using java**